SSRS Parameter Selections Automatically Changing
I have a SSRS dataset that grabs report date ranges from a view. Here's a simplified version of the view:
SELECT [Label], [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT 'Current Month' AS [Label]
        ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS [StartDate]
        ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, - 1, GETDATE()), 0) AS [EndDate]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Previous Month' AS [Label]
        ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AS [StartDate]
        ,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS [EndDate]
    ) dates
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT CAST([StartDate] AS CHAR(30))+'|'+CAST([EndDate] AS CHAR(30)) AS [Value]
    ) date_ranges

I then add this as a shared dataset to a SSRS report and map it to a "DateRange" parameter. This way, a user can select "Current Month" and the parameter will send "Sep  1 2024 12:00AM           |Oct  1 2024 12:00AM           " to the main report logic. The reason I'm doing it this way is to allow retrieving the date range directly from the report (using LEFT(30) and RIGHT(30)) rather than having to use a translation table that might be on a different server than the rest of the query or add a case statement to every report to translate the range name.
This works great except for one hitch - it was brought to my attention that at the end/beginning of a month, people who picked "Current Month" as the date range have their subscriptions auto-updated to "Previous Month". My guess is that this is happening because the value of the parameter last time it ran is equal to the current value for "Previous Month", so SSRS is assuming that's what their selection was?
Is there any way to prevent this from happening? And/or is this just a really stupid way of doing things and I should do something different altogether?

I'm not sure I fully understand the issue you face but personally, I would have the parameter value be a simple 0 or 1 for current/previous month, then do the date range logic in the main dataset query.
